# ios Swift Google map sdk not working in iPhone6s+

Tags: ios, swift

Xcode Issues:
GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GTMStringEncoding.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

When I Set "NO" on ENABLE_BITCODE app will be crash in iPhone6s+. But, it will work in iPhone4s.

Comment: what is the crash log?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set in build settings Build Active architectures only  enable Yes and enableBitcode No then it will work

Comment: Hi, Thanks lot. I'll try it